# How to change my credentials in git bash?

Tags: git, bash, credentials

I need to change username and password from host. 
When I use `$ git config --global credential.helper default`, it should ask new user and password next time I'm working with repo, but it isn't works.

Hot to change my username and password?

Comment: Please define more clearly "it isn't work".

Answer (score 1):

I got myself here having the same problem and I found the solution in the git docs. Write the following lines and everything should be fine, for your next commhrigit sits.

```
$ git config credential.helper store
$ git push http://example.com/repo.git
  Username: <type your username>
  Password: <type your password>
```

Here is a link to the docs : [git scm](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store)

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you use ssh url for the repo rather than https and then try running:

git config --global user.name myusername
git config --global user.email myemail